# How to change font and its size in QLPreviewViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

In my iOS app, I'm using `QLPreviewViewController()`. It is presenting a **.txt** file. I want to change the **type** of the font and its **size**. So is it possible to change it or I'm not able to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Create a Theme struct like so...

```
struct Theme {
    static func apply() {
        guard let hearderFont = UIFont(familyName: "Lobster", size: UIFont.systemFontSize * 2) else {
            NSLog("Failed to load header font")
            return
        }
        
        guard let primaryFont = UIFont(familyName: "Quicksand") else {
            NSLog("Failed to load application font")
            return
        }
        
        let tintColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.56, green: 0.35, blue: 0.97, alpha: 1)
        
        UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window??.tintColor = tintColor
        
        let navBar = UINavigationBar.appearance()
        navBar.titleTextAttributes = [.font: hearderFont]
        
        let navBarLabel = UILabel.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UINavigationBar.self])
        navBarLabel.font = primaryFont
        
        let label = UILabel.appearance()
        label.font = primaryFont
        
        let barButton = UIBarButtonItem.appearance()
        barButton.setTitleTextAttributes([.font: primaryFont], for: .normal)
        barButton.setTitleTextAttributes([.font: primaryFont], for: .highlighted)
        
        let buttonLabel = UILabel.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UIButton.self])
        buttonLabel.font = primaryFont
    }
}
```

Then call it in your AppDelegate when your app loads like so:

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        Theme.apply()
        return true
    }
```

You also have to add an entry in your Info.plist file.
'Fonts provided by application' is an array of 'Item 0', 'Item 1' where the values are the font file names.

Make sure you have these assets added to your build resources or it will never work.

If you want to see this code in action and play with it you can find it on
Github here:
https://github.com/DEV3L/swift-selfiegram

Happy Coding!